# How to include config file in SharePoint empty farm solution in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config, sharepoint-2013

I am a starter to farm solution in SharePoint.So I open VS2015->Selected Environment-->and got to the empty project template-->And after that in solution Explorer I got the files.But than in solution their is no web.config file..

How can I create web.config file manually for share point 2013 farm solution

Answer (score 0):

A SharePoint farm solution should not typically need to include a web.config file.

A SharePoint solution is deployed to an existing SharePoint environment, and each web application in that environment will already have its own web.config file.

Comment: I ma working on farm solution I opened VS 2015-->Selected SharePoint office and apps-->and selected  empty project for farm solution and than pressed ok--> than selected the url on which SharePoint is working.On opening application no web.config file is der

Comment: Why are you looking for a web.config file?

Comment: actually whenver i want to open a external URL application in sharepoint its giving me a error to add the refrence for that in web.config file.I want to open a url of my external application in viusal webpart in iframe  and show on load of sharepoint screen

Comment: You desire to change the web server security settings. That should be done by logging on to the server, not through a SharePoint farm solution. (Think of it this way: the web server hosts the farm solution, but the web server is not controlled by it.)